# Failed to run Android SDK manager

Tags: android, development

I have installed Android SDK in my Eclipse EE IDE. Now I'm trying to open the Android SDK manager but getting error as [image: in following image]

Even I tried to see the android console as shown in image, No error shows in console.
[is LogCat console for Android? I searched error for as android console].

Thank you

Comment: Having same problem :(

Comment: I reinstalled the Eclipse and android SDK. now it's working perfectly.

Answer (score 8):

try this

```
chmod -R uga+rwx <android-sdk-folder>
```

Answer (score 5):

This error occurs when the Ubuntu user logged in doesn't have access to the folder in which the Android SDK files are located.

Make sure to open nautilus and set permissions accordingly and give permissions to read/write/execute.

I did that and it worked like magic.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
chmod +x <ADTFolder>/sdk/tools/android
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to tools folder in "sdk"
2. In the "tools" folder available "android" file then go to the properties of the file in that click permission(at the top).
3. Check "Allow executing file as a program"(bottom left) then close that
4. Then run sdk it works, if it is not work copy your sdk file into your Home and set the path
5. Imp: you should check if your sdk tools and platform-tools path is set.